# NSMutableArray Global without an app delegate for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, uiviewcontroller

If I declare an NSMutable Array in a ViewController, is there a way I can make it global without using the app delegate?

Comment: You can use singleton for that. You might have to create a separate class and define it in that.

Comment: The AppDelegate is a singleton. There's only one AppeDelegate instance in your app. Creating a separate singleton class would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class method to return the `NSMutableArray` from your `UIViewController` subclass, e.g.:

```
static NSMutableArray *array;

+ (NSMutableArray *)array {
    if (!array) {
        array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    }
    return array;
}
```

Then you could obtain the array instance from anywhere with `[MyViewController array]`.